# adding two decimal number using two's complement

Tags: binary, decimal, twos-complement

**Given Question:**

Assume 151 and 214 are signed 8-bit decimal integers stored in two’s complement format. Calculate 151+214, the result should be written in decimal. Check for overflow. Hint: overflow occurs when the result of adding two positive numbers is negative.

**Instructor's Solution:**

**Step 1:**

Write the two numbers in binary:

214 = 11010110

151 = 10010111

**Step 2:**

Rewrite using two's complement representation:

214 = 11010110 = 00101010

151 = 10010111 = 01101001

**Step 3:**

Convert results of two’s complement to decimal:

214 = 11010110 = 00101010 = -105

151 = 10010111 = 01101001 = -42

**Step 4:**

Add: 100101010+01101001 = 10010011

**Step 5:**

Convert results to decimal:
10010011 = -147

**Conclusion: As can be noted, there is overflow**

**My questions are:**

**In step 1:**
Why are the MSBs of the results of converting 214 and 151 to binary equal to 1 (negative) when 214 and 151 are both positive? Aren’t their values in binary equal to 011010110 and 010010111 respectively?

**In step 3:**
After converting the results of two’s complement of both numbers to decimal, why is the sign negative if the MSB is 0 (positive)?

Comment: The MSB is 1 because the values exceed the *signed* range for 8-bit values (0..127). And a computer can't just add another bit. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In step 1, the numbers are too large for an 8 bit two's complement number. The largest 8 bit signed integer is 127. Step 3 is showing that if you write those numbers in 8 bits, you get a negative number. The conversion is showing which negative number you get. So to tell which number 11010110 represents, take the two's complement, then negate that.

Comment: thanks! one question, when you said "So to tell which number 11010110 represents, take the two's complement, then negate that.", what do you mean by negating that?

Comment: When you complement it, you get 00101010. That's 42. So 11010110 is -42.